# how to ssh run a tail and then send data to a mysql database

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, ssh

This code SSH's and then runs a tail command on a remote hots. I would now like to pass that tailed data into a mysql database using a local script called  insertPerfmon.sh.

How do I pass data generated in a ssh session into the local shell script insertPerfmon.sh.  The local shell script is going to send data to the database. However, I need to get it there first.

```
             ( ssh -nq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
              -i $PEM_PATH/$PEM_FILE $USER@${host} -p $REMOTE_PORT \
             tail -n 5  $REMOTE_HOME/data/PerfMon*  |insertPerfmon.sh)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `insertPerfmon.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mydata=$(cat)
echo $mydata
# process & send $mydata to database
```

The following should work:

```
<your_ssh_command> | bash insertPerfmon.sh
```

Comment: Hi, I added bash insertPerfmon.sh as above. However, no data being passed through to it. Perfmon.sh is the following. echo "Perfmon Data=$1"

Comment: What does your ssh command output? Strip `| bash insertPerfmon.sh` and show the output.

Comment: @Sascha: You should modify the *.sh script according to the answer. Try again. You should use `Perfmon_Data=$(cat)` instead of `Perfmon_Data=$1` to read data from stdin.

Comment: When I write it to a file it is fine. However, I want to hold it in a variable and then send to a database. Sample data below: 1434273570748,193682,localhost Network I/O unit=kb:bytesrecv,,,,,true,0,0,0,0,ip-172-31-14-229,0,0
1434273570748,0,localhost Swap unit=mb:used,,,,,true,0,0,0,0,ip-172-31-14-229,0,0
1434273571748,148

Comment: Do not use `Perfmon_Data=$1`. Use `Perfmon_Data=$(cat)`

Comment: Thanks so much this fixed a problem that has stopped me sleeping